# How do I make a dynamically expanding array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Ok I have this part of code:

```
def Reading_Old_File(self, Path, turn_index, SKU):
        print "Reading Old File! Turn Index = ", turn_index, "SKU= ", SKU
        lenght_of_array=0
        array_with_data=[]
        if turn_index==1:
            reading_old_file = open(Path,'rU')
            data=np.genfromtxt(reading_old_file, delimiter="''", dtype=None)
            for index, line_in_data in enumerate(data, start=0):
                if index<3:
                    print index, "Not Yet"
                if index>=3:
                    print ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Reading All Old Items"
                    i=index-3
                    old_items_data[i]=line_in_data.split("\t")
                    old_items_data[i]=[lines_old.strip()for lines_old in old_items_data]
                    print old_items_data[i]
                    print len(old_items_data)
```

So what I am doing here is, I'm reading a file, on my first turn, I want to read it all, and keep all data, so it would be something like:

```
old_items_data[1]=['123','dog','123','dog','123','dog']
old_items_data[2]=['124','cat','124','cat','124','cat']
old_items_data[n]=['amount of list members is equal each time']
```

each line of the file should be stored in list, so I can use it in future for comparing, when turn_index will be greater than 2 I'll compare coming line with lines in every list(array) by iterating over all lists.
So question is how do I do it, or is there any better way to compare lists?
I'm new to python so maybe someone could help me with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you declaring `old_items_data`? It seems like you just start putting items in a list that you never created.

Comment: Yeah looks like i've deleted it, but i'm going to add old_items_data=[] after function Reading_Old_File starts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `append`.

```
old_items_data.append(line_in_data.split("\t"))
```

Comment: Will I then be able to access them all, whenever I need them? I thought old values will be overwritten, no?

Comment: `append` adds them to the end of the list, which is exactly what you want. If you create an empty list `old_items_data = []` and try to access indices like `old_items_data[0]` you will get index out of bounds errors.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the package `pandas` for this. It will not only be much quicker, but also simpler. Use `pandas.read_table` to import the data (specifying delimiter and row-skipping can be done here by passing arguments to `sep` and `skiprows`). Then, use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` to apply your function to the rows of your data.

The speed gains are going to come from the fact that `pandas` was optimized to perform actions across lists like this (in the case of a `pandas` DataFrame, these would be called rows). This applies to both importing the data and applying a function to every row. The simplicity gains should hopefully be clear.